# Display form window as small as possible (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, qt, attribute-form

Is it possible to always set the form window (standard form of QGIS) to its minimum size? Currently, the form window retains the size of the last opened form window. However, I have forms with many and with few entries. If I open a form with many entries first and then one with few, the window is too large for the latter.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean your custom plugin window or is it some standard QGIS window? Can you attach a screenshot of this window(s)?

Comment: It's the standart QGIS window.

Comment: Might this other question be of any help to you?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286948/setting-attribute-form-window-resizable-in-qgis-3

Comment: No, I'm looking for a solution to always open the Form window in its optimal (minimal) size, regardless of previously opened forms.

Answer (score 5):

That's only half the answer to your question. Using [adjustSize()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#adjustSize), you can automatically resize the form window. At the moment it's not clear to me how to catch the standard form call. Presumably you have to change the behavior for each of the buttons in the QGIS interface: `Add Record`, `Add Polygon`, `Add Line`, `Add Point`.

After you find a way to catch the form opening signal, the code with the quick fixes can be put in `startup.py`, located in the `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3` folder (for OS Windows).

```py
layer_name = 'min'
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    feature_form = iface.getFeatureForm(layer, feature)
    feature_form.adjustSize()
    feature_form.show()
```

[image: screencast] <== click to watch

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to add your own code to the layer settings. The code will be executed **only for this layer**. This code works **after** the `OK` button was pressed (if the `Cancel` button was pressed - it does nothing).

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog

def custom_adjust_size(dialog, layer, feature):
    parent = dialog.parent()
    if isinstance(parent, QDialog):
        parent.adjustSize()
```

[image: settings] <== click to enlarge

[image: screencast] <== click to watch